# Can you detect whether an application is in immersive mode in Fragment.onCreateView?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-4.4-kitkat

In a fragment I have implemented a `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener` so that I can enter/exit immersive mode when `onSingleTapUp` is detected.

A `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is used to move between these fragments on swipe left/right. If you enter immersive mode then swipe to a new fragment the UI remains in immersive mode.

However, in the `onCreateView` method of the new fragment I need to detect whether the UI is in immersive mode to when creating my listener.

I have tried calling `getSystemUiVisibility()` on the new view but this returns `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE`.

Is there a method for detecting whether the application is in immersive mode from any view or fragment regardless of whether that initiated the transition to immersive mode?

Comment: Are you calling `getSystemUiVisibility()` from a `View` within the `Fragment`, or via a `View` attached to the layout of the parent `Activity`?  The docs aren't clear on this, but I'm wondering if using a view (even a 0 sized or invisible but not gone) one which is attached to the `Activity` would report it properly.

Comment: @LarrySchiefer I was calling get/setSystemUiVisibility() on the `View` associated with the `Fragment`. Using the `View` returned by `getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView()` lets me access the visibility across fragments. Feel free to add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Mark, it sounds like you may have gotten it resolved based on my previous comment: use a `View` owned by the `Activity` to call `getSystemUiVisibility()` rather than the `Fragment`.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is looking for a more in-depth answer. To check if the window is in immersive vs non-immersive you can do something use:

```
(getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility() & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE) == View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
```

An example of it's usage for swapping between immersive and normal:

```
private void toggleImmersive() {
    if ((getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility() & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE) == View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility( // Go fullscreen
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    } else {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility( // Go immersive
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using

`WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` 

for fullscreen mode but none of those Flags available on fullscreen on api 32? any suggestions?